# Custom Block Twig: File field how to get direct link to file?

Tags: theming

How can I get the direct URL to a file field in twig? I am able to do this for images, but with a file field, it comes up blank.

WORKS

```
{% set media_img_url = file_url(content.field_background_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) %}
```

DOESN't WORK

```
{% set media_file_url = file_url(content.field_cta_file.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) %}
```

Comment: Are you sure both structures are the same like that? And is the second field set to display in the given view mode of the content type? It has to not be hidden from display.

Answer (score 1):

`#item` is as far as I know only added by the image field formatter, so it's unlikely you'll find it in other field types.

Instead you can use the block content entity to get field values, for example:

```
{{ elements.content['#block_content'].field_file.0.entity.uri.value }}
```

This works independently of field formatters and as commented by @Kevin also when a field is hidden.

Comment: So this works, but I get a file path of: 

public://2018-11/myfile.pdf

where does that folder go off of?

Comment: This is the raw field value of the uri field, use file_url() to transform it to a URL, like you already did successfully in your question.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, {% set media_file_url = file_url(elements.content['#block_content'].field_cta_file.0.entity.uri.value) %}   You are a lifesaver!!!